# function with sql query return undefied

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await, promise

I'm trying to write a function in node that make an SQL query, and return true or false based on the query result.
but because the query is a sync function, it is keep moving on in the code and return `undefied` befor it even get the query result.

i tryed to use async and await, but it's not working,evene if i place the return condition out of the query parenthesis. it return `Promise { <pending> }`

```
async function isUserExist(userName) {
  const selectUser = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?';
  await con.query(selectUser, [userName], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('rows: ', rows);
    if (rows.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
};
```

becaus the promise, i tried to place `.then(()=>{})` , but it donn't compiled well in any end of parenthsis

what can i do? i need to use this a lott
thanks

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using async/await, no need to pass in the callback function to the `con.query`.

```
 async function isUserExist(userName) {
  const selectUser = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?';
  try {
    const rows = await con.query(selectUser, [userName]);
     
     /* Instead of using if, you can directly return 
     the result of the comparison 
     which will always evaluates to true/false. */

    return rows.length === 0;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Comment: it's crashing with this error:
 const [err, rows] = await con.query(selectUser, [userName])
                      ^

TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
    at isUserExist (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\gitHub\accounting-system\server\addCustomer.js:28:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.12.0

Comment: It should be just `const rows =` and not `const [err, rows] =` and the line `if (err) throw err` needs to be removed.

Comment: it's still return promise pending, and rows is a big object, i don't even find the query result in it.

Comment: @HodayaChayo "it still return promise pending": only if you forget to `await` the call to `isUserExist`. Also you should probably use a `COUNT` query instead of selecting all columns and then checking only for whether there are any rows. - Also, which MySQL library is this? Maybe it doesn't even support promises. Make sure to use a modern client.